# Is "associated a subset of Ω" grammatical in this sentence?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, inversion

> Let  and Ω be sets, and suppose [that with each element  of  there is associated a subset of Ω which we denote by ].

Is "associated a subset of Ω" grammatical in this sentence?

An anonymous person said that the word "there" is inverted with the noun phrase "a subset of Ω." But I think the pronoun "there" is the grammatical subject of the bracketed *that*-clause, and the noun phrase "an associated subset of Ω which we denote by " should be the semantic subject of the clause. The noun "subset" would be the head of this semantic subject.

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: In my opinion the sentence *sounds* grammatically wrong, but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure sounds a little weird, but it makes sense. Here's an example from **[1 Corinthians 12:8, New International Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians+12&version=NIV)**:

> To one [person] there is given through the Spirit a message of wisdom.

This can be reorganized in the following way to eliminate existential **there**:

> A message of wisdom is given through the Spirit to one [person].

I also find OP's exact text in **[a textbook published by McGraw-Hill](https://jgcsr.org/wp-content/uploads/Walter_Rudin_Principles_of_Mathematical_Analysisz-lib.org_.pdf)**, which makes it pretty legitimate in my eyes.

I find this similar usage in a very carefully typeset handout used by **[some math class](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Ematkerr/5031/A1IA.pdf)** in Washington University of St. Louis, a reputable school:

> to each element of I there is associated a subset S<sub>i</sub> ⊂ S.

You would have to ask a mathematician to know if the structure is *commonly* used in the field.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!